# Do nested functions which capture variables allocate

Tags: scala, closures, nested-function

A nested function in scala can capture a variable in the parent function.

e.g.

```scala
def outer = {
    var a = 0
    def inner = {
        a = 42
    }
    inner()
    a
}
```

In C# this is implemented by storing all captured variables on a struct, and passing that struct in byref. This avoids the nested function allocating unless you convert it into a function object. See [this example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEBMBGAsAKBQZgAJ1CBhQgb10JuKIEsA7GQgeQFd4EAKASkuq0hTFhEIBeQgAYA3IKE0UAFkIBJRo0R8JAPkJjJStHJwLa6zT14mzigOz6btAL65nQA===) in sharplab.

In scala however you can't pass variables by ref, so the only way this could work is by storing all captured variables on an object, and passing that object in.

Does that mean that every invocation of a nested function will allocate if it captures any variables in scala?

Comment: The variables are captured when the nested function is created, not when it is invoked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `a` itself is still in the `outer` method's stack frame, while the object that it refers to is allocated on the heap, as all Java objects are (even when `a` is supposed to represent a primitive type).

By running `javap -v` on that code of yours, we can see that `a` is actually a final variable of type `scala.runtime.IntRef`, which holds an integer field that can be updated. The nested method `inner` is turned into a static method that accepts one argument of type `IntRef` and sets its `elem` field to 42. This is somewhat similar to the C# approach, but creates one object for each variable instead of a struct to hold all of them.

```
public int outer();                                                                                          
descriptor: ()I                                                                                                         
flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC                                                                                              
Code:                                                                                                                     
stack=1, locals=2, args_size=1                                                                                             
0: iconst_0                                                                                                             
1: invokestatic  #16                 // Method scala/runtime/IntRef.create:
(I)Lscala/runtime/IntRef;                    
4: astore_1                                                                                                             
5: aload_1                                                                                                              
6: invokestatic  #20                 // Method inner$1:(Lscala/runtime/IntRef;)V                                        
9: aload_1                                                                                                             
10: getfield      #24                 // Field scala/runtime/IntRef.elem:I                                              
13: ireturn
```

Edit: Let's try it with a `String` this time:

```
class ClosureTest {
    def outer = {
        var a = ""
        def inner() = {
            a = "42"
        }
        inner()
        a
    }
}
```

Output from `javap`:

```
public java.lang.String outer();                                                                                          
descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/String;                                                                                        
flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC                                                                                              
Code:                                                                                                                     
stack=1, locals=2, args_size=1                                                                                             
0: ldc           #12                 // String                                                                          
2: invokestatic  #18                 // Method scala/runtime/ObjectRef.create:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/runtime/ObjectRef;                                                                                                                     
5: astore_1                                                                                                             
6: aload_1                                                                                                              
7: invokestatic  #22                 // Method inner$1: (Lscala/runtime/ObjectRef;)V                                    
10: aload_1                                                                                                             
11: getfield      #26                 // Field 
scala/runtime/ObjectRef.elem:Ljava/lang/Object;                          
14: checkcast     #28                 // class java/lang/String                                                         
17: areturn
```

This time, since `String` is not a primitive, the class `ObjectRef` (which has a type parameter representing the wrapped value) is used, but it's still basically the same thing. Even though the JVM doesn't allow you to have `ref` parameters like C# does, objects are still passed by reference, so the value of the object/primitive that `a` holds can still be modified.

Here's a [link](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.scala-native/nativelib_native0.2_2.11/latest/scala/runtime/package.html) to the only documentation I could find. There are lots of other classes, like `BooleanRef`, `FloatRef`, and also their volatile counterparts, like `VolatileDoubleRef`, `VolatileObjectRef`, etc. Each of these classes basically just have one mutable public field that the compiler uses when the "real" value of the captured variable is needed.